# Why does installing grunt(npm install grunt --save-dev) into my project stops in between and doesn't make any chnages to package.json?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gruntjs, npm-install, brunch

[Installing grunt stops in between and does not move forward, please see image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1LWz.png)

Reasons why this is happening and solution to it?
Uglified js files via brunch before but it is no more compatible on new windows versions so installing grunt.
No errors are shown in the console, the process continues smoothly for sometimes then stops and never moves ahead.